# Bathroom tile cut without chipping

Tags: ceramic-tile, cutting, cover

So Im installing ceramic tiles through out my home and i reached an area that is causing some concern. As im entering the bathroom and need to make some cuts up against the bathtub. But I've noticed that some of the tiles chip (small chips) when making cuts with machine and I was wondering if there was a way to make a clean cut with a portable tool?  I want to make sure if i need to make a cut that it will look clean since i will be unable to cover it with molding .

Or is there some thing that i can buy that is water resist that is like floor molding to hide the chips

Attached is the kind of tile i am installing

[link](https://www.homedepot.com/p/LifeProof-Autumn-Wood-6-in-x-24-in-Porcelain-Floor-and-Wall-Tile-14-55-sq-ft-case-LP32624HD1PR/304207285?MERCH=REC-_-rv_search_plp_rr-_-308500678;308500672;303517940;304603935;307659961;303518055;205626148;303309258;302026093;304063581;203183245;303320377;203183251;204688439;310553405;204688440;308658715;308658737;205472964;308658754;308615611;308658628;203183248;203183263;-_-304207285-_-N)

Comment: Use a diamond blade on a hand saw and cut from the glazed side to the soft side only cutting on the push stroke.

Comment: It is difficult to get a perfectly straight line with a hand saw (at least for me!).  Perhaps the problem is your technique or machine setup.  Google "cut porcelain without chipping"

Comment: I would rent a wet tile saw. diamond blades when wet don’t chip much but hot they are not much better and even worse than a score and snap method. I think my son purchased a really cheap wet diamond saw from harbor freight for well under 100 , he did not realize what my big one was until he showed me his new tool.